# Elasticsearch [mlt] query does not support [ids]]

Tags: elasticsearch

I recently update elasticsearch from 0.9x to 1.0.3, and i find more_like_this add a new parameters: ids from doc http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html. However when i want to use it like:

```
{
  query: { 
    more_like_this: {         
      min_term_freq: 1,
      max_query_terms: 12,
      min_doc_freq: 1,
      ids: ["doc_id_xxxxx"]
    } 
  }
}
```

It returns: **nested: QueryParsingException[[index] [mlt] query does not support [ids]];**

but when changing ids to like_text, it works fine.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the official document is a little earlier than version release. So the parameter will be available when 1.2.0 is out. https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/6272